# Meshmixer create solid

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, meshmixer

I have this .stl that I downloaded and I need to create a solid of this 3D. However, if I click "Make solid", it doesn't work.

How can I do? I think the problem is the black layer but I don't know how to resolve.

Before make solid:

[image: Screenshot of Meshmixer - before make solid]

After make solid:

[image: Screenshot of Meshmixer - after make solid]

I need to make solid and the black layer is deleted when I do it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g-YaF1k_X5FU1Y-SgWiGCXC4k_nADohk/view?usp=sharing

PS: The other object are different item, so if they are there or not is the same

Comment: Hi and welcome. We *may* require more information, please [edit] and add more details.

Comment: Other? I have download the file, I don't much more but I need to make solid and the black layer is deleted when I do it

Comment: Do you have a link to where you downloaded the `.stl` file from? If we can reproduce the issue, then maybe a solution can be found. Please [edit] and add the link to your answer (don't add info in the comments).

Comment: Your object browser shows three objects in the first image, only one in the second. Are the missing pieces those of the other two items in the first image?

Comment: The other two objects are different item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Make solid requires an enclosed volume

To run the make solid operation, the selected parts need to enclose a volume. In case the volume is not fully enclosed, the program tries to solve a solution that closes the open surface.

The black layer is most likely failing to compute because its normals are flipped. This means it does not enclose a surface, it excludes anything between the surfaces from being inside the body defined by it - it is **everything but**. This is solved as "this surface does not enclose anything, so I cut it out" but for where it creates a valid solution in the area of the white surface before the operation.

This leaves you with the white retained part after the operation.

## To fix this is an in-depth project

Fixing such errors is quite involved. You will need to do the following steps, depending on your program to alter:

- flip the surfaces so that it shows outside
- make sure that the body is closed, possibly by adding missing surfaces

Comment: How can I enclose volume?